# Sequence that converges as for the norm but not almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

How can I find a sequence that converges as for the norm but doesn't converge almost everywhere, in some space $L^p$ ??

Could you give me some hints ??

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Divide $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals with equal length, call each one $I_k^n$ where $1\leq k\leq n$, consider $f_{n+k}=\chi_{I_k^n}$, which is a sequence of function converges to $f=0$ in $L^1$  (since the length eventually converges to $0$) but nowhere converges (since $\forall x\in[0,1], x\in I_k^n$ for some $k$ for each $n$.)

Comment: Does "converges as for the norm" means that it converges in $L^1$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar It means converge in $L^p$. But since you want a example to your statement, it suffices to consider $L^1$

Comment: I see... Could you explain me why the function converges to $f=0$ in $L^1$ but nowhere converges??

Comment: @MaryStar Do you understand the construction? It converges in $L^1$ since the integral of $f_n$ is area of the rectangle, with height 1 and width converges to $0$. It doesn't coverge at any $x$, since for each $x$, you can find a subsequence $f_{n_k}(x)=1 \forall k$, so $f_n(x)$ can't converge to $0$

Comment: $f_{n_k}=\chi_{I_k^n}$ means that it is $1$ if $x \in \chi_{I_k^n}$ and $0$ if $x \notin \chi_{I_k^n}$, right?? Why is the integral of $f_n$ the area of the rectangle?? Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: @MaryStar Because here $I_k^n$ is just an interval, and $f_{n+k}$ is a step function hence Riemann integrable, hence the Lebesgue integeral is just it's Riemann integral.

Comment: What do you mean with $f_{n+k}$?? Isn't it $f_{n_k}$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar yeah, you can say that. But I use $n+k$ as the index since $n+k$ follows the definition of sequence ( a map from $\mathbb{N}$) and $n_k$ looks like subsequence of a sequence. But basically we are referring to the same thing.